# how to keep memcache and datastore in sync

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

suppose I have million users registered with my app. now there's a new user, and I want to show him who all in his contacts have this app installed. A user can have many contacts, let's say 500. now if I go to get an entity for each contact from datastore then it's very time and money consuming. memcache is a good option, but I've to keep it in sync for that Kind. I can get dedicated memcache for such a large data, but how do I sync it? my logic would be, if it's not there in memcache, assume that that contact is not registered with this app. A backend module with manual scaling can be used to keep both in sync. But I don't know how good this design is. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: It's Java. it's a webservice on servlet.

Comment: :(.  Python has ndb that does exactly that for you :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how memcache is designed to be used. You should never rely on memcache. Keys can drop at any time. Therefore, in your case, you can never be sure if a contact exists or not.

I don't know what your problem with datastore is? Datastore is designed to read data very fast - take advantage of it.

When new users install your app, create a lookup entity with the phone number as the key. You don't necessarily need any other properties. Something like this:

```
Entity contactLookup = new Entity("ContactLookup", "somePhoneNumber");
datastore.put(contactLookup);
```

That will keep a log of who's got the app installed.

Then, to check which of your users contacts are already using your app, you can create an array of keys out of the phone numbers from the users address book (with their permission of course!), and perform a batch get. Something like this:

```
Set<Key> keys = new HashSet<Key>();

for (String phoneNumber : phoneNumbers)
    keys.add(KeyFactory.createKey("ContactLookup", phoneNumber));

Map<Key, Entity> entities = datastore.get(keys);
```

Now, `entities` will be those contacts that have your app installed.

You may need to batch the keys to reduce load. The python api does this for you, but not sure about the java apis. But even if your users has 500 contacts, it's only 5 queries (assuming batches of 100).

Side note: you may want to consider hashing phone numbers for storage.

Comment: You cannot use Memcache to decide if an entity is not present, but you can certainly use Memcache to check if an entity already exists - and avoid a trip to the datastore if it does. This is the most common use case for Memcache.

Answer (score 1):

Memcache is a good option to reduce costs and improve performance, but you should not assume that it is always available. Even a dedicated Memcache may fail or an individual record can be evicted. Besides, all this synchronization logic will be very complicated and error-prone.

You can use Memcache to indicate if a contact is registered with the app, in which case you do not have to check the datastore for that contact. But I would recommend checking all contacts not found in Memcache in the Datastore.

Verifying if a record is present in a datastore is fast and inexpensive. You can use `.get(java.lang.Iterable<Key> keys)` method to retrieve the entire list with a single datastore call.

You can further improve performance by creating an entity with no properties for registered users. This way there will be no overhead in retrieving these entities.

Comment: I guess I've not explained this question correctly. when a user installs this app on his mobile, client app will send user's contact list from mobile to server. that list can be of more than 500 contacts. now server need to check if these contacts are registered with this app. if server is able to get an Entity (key=contact.number) then it can assume that contact is registered. there is no point to get into datastore, I want to conclude from memcache only. that's why I want to keep memcache and datastore in sync with backend instance.

Comment: In order to keep it in sync, you will have to periodically retrieve all records from the datastore. Now, if memcache fails, your app will assume that none of the contacts are registered with the app until the next sync completes. This will force you to run these sync frequently, which becomes expensive. I will update my answer.

Comment: yup, that's why am looking for some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use python and therefore don't have access to NDB, the suggestion would be to, when you add a user, add him to memcache and create an async query (or a task queue job) to push the same data to your datastore.  Like that memcache gets pushed first, and then eventually the datastore follows.  They'll always be in sync.

Then all you need to do is to first query your memcache when you do "gets" (because memcache is always in sync since you push there first), and if memcache returns empty (being volatile and whatnot), then query the actual datastore to "re fill" memcache

Comment: I cannot decide on when to refill. If memcache returns empty, it can be either that contact is not registered with this app or Key was removed from memcache. I don't want to go to datastore for all contacts.

Comment: you want to keep memcache synced at ALL times?.... that sounds VERY costy... you'll need a cron job in the background to run VERY often and sync everything back.... and with memcache being volatile, this is not a good option cost wise I think because it will eat up your quotas and will cost a good amount.

Comment: I thought so, that's why here asking for a better design :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not how memcache was ever meant to be used unfortunately..... you can't be sure it'll be there ever... even with a cron job, you'd need to run it basically every second to make sure your data is synced at ALL time.  And what will happen if your datastore ever grows too big for the memcache?  I don't see a real solution to your problem the way you present it

Comment: there must be some option. for example, whatsapp does the same thing, it shows who all has installed this app in my contacts. they may not be on appengine, but something similar on this platform.

Comment: you know the INTERNAL coding of whatsapp and are sure they are not using datastore?  even if they are on a similar platform?  Memcache is volatile, there is NO WAY to ensure how long the data will stay.  it's the design of memcache.  You're trying to use the tool in a different way than it's meant to be used.... I see no way honestly.  I'm trying to see why you're against using datastore

Comment: you're right. am just looking for alternatives for datastore just because it will be time consuming if user has so many contacts. thanks for your inputs.

Comment: You can probably quicken the datastore by using a different model... maybe try putting the user as a parent and his contacts as child?  will let you do faster ancestor queries, but your datastore might end up spider webbed